# CSS :before width

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

Simple question here I can't figure out (probably the solution is ultra-easy I just cannot see it). If you hover the mouse on the `a`-element, the `:before` style takes the width till the end of the page.

Why is that? Any solutions to make it inherit the width from the `li`-element only (make it always as wide as the navigation link)?

```css
/* navbar style */

#sidebar-wrapper {

}

.navbar {
  padding: 0px;
}

.navbar li:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #aaa;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
  z-index: -1;
}

.navbar li:hover:before {
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar li:first-child:before {
  background-color: #ec1b5a
}

.navbar li:nth-child(2):before {
  background-color: #3DEC1B
}

.navbar li:nth-child(3):before {
  background-color: #D3EC1A
}

.navbar li:nth-child(4):before {
  background-color: #1B9AEC
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Matt Chowski's portfolio</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="nav justify-content-between" id="sidebar">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="navbar-brand"><a class="nav-link">Mateusz Wojciechowski</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar" id="navlinks">
                <li><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

</body>
```

Thank you for all the help <3

Comment: Forgot to add, it takes the width of the whole <ul> instead of the single <li>. Ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this code.

All I did is added `position: relative;` to li and also added `display: flex` to ul
https://codepen.io/Izulito/pen/xXmOqq

Comment: wow thanks man! got confused because with bootstrap I didn't have to add that

Comment: It is the preference on Stack Overflow to include the code directly in your answer instead of an external link. This is because external links can change or be removed at any time. SO provides its own snippet editor to add and run snippets of code, see: [How to create a runnable code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)